# Memory leaks with SDL_CreateWindow/SDL_DestroyWindow in SDL2

Tags: c, memory-leaks, sdl-2

Valgrind reports 523 memory leaks, totalling nearly 1Mb, each much like the following:

```
==26609== 1 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 523
==26609==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==26609==    by 0x4EB0896: _XlcDefaultMapModifiers (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==26609==    by 0x4EB0C6A: XSetLocaleModifiers (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==26609==    by 0x4940824: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.10.0)
==26609==    by 0x494745A: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.10.0)
==26609==    by 0x4919F6A: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.10.0)
==26609==    by 0x4919D26: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2-2.0.so.0.10.0)
==26609==    by 0x1203A3: open_window (scrSDL.c:247)
==26609==    by 0x120D4E: new_Screen (scrSDL.c:564)
==26609==    by 0x10C608: initgraphicsmode (display.c:253)
==26609==    by 0x110518: new_Display (display.c:1669)
==26609==    by 0x10BABC: initialise (chambers.c:220)
```

The line scrSDL.c:247 opens a window (I've included the whole function including debug code, I'll post the debug output below):

```
/**
 * Open a window for a screen.
 * @param screen The screen to use.
 */
static void open_window (Screen *screen)
{
    /* open window and surface */
    window = SDL_CreateWindow
        ("CGALIB2", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
         SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 640, 400,
         SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    printf ("%p = SDL_CreateWindow(...)\n", window); /**/

    /* make the window behave like a 320x200 screen */
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer (window, -1, 0);
    SDL_RenderSetLogicalSize(renderer, 320, 200);

    /* refresh the screen with the buffer contents */
    draw_display_entry (screen, 0, 0, 320, 200);
}
```

My first conclusion was that maybe I forget to close the window, so I put in debug code at the point where I *think* I close the window; here's the whole function:

```
/**
 * Close the current window.
 * @param screen The screen to close.
 */
static void close_window (Screen *screen)
{
    SDL_DestroyRenderer (renderer);
    printf ("SDL_DestroyWindow (%p)\n", window); /**/
    SDL_DestroyWindow (window);
}
```

And it turns out I do close the window; stdout from the run of the program that produced the above valgrind output is this:

```
0x6bbf2d0 = SDL_CreateWindow(...)
SDL_DestroyWindow (0x6bbf2d0)
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is there anything else I need to do to clean up this window properly?

Comment: Difficult to tell whether that's the implementation of SDL2's fault without further testing?